# How to run steam game, connect to the server and execute console cmd using python steam lib?

Tags: python, steam

I am using [this](https://github.com/ValvePython/steam) library to communicate with steam. I need to "run" a game, connect to the game server and execute console command (I actually want to get players list with their steam64 IDs). Docs don't have much information about this.

EDIT:
I have an example code that use Messaging (?) interface to post friend request. I think I should use it to execute game commands:

```py
from steam.enums import EResult
from steam.core.msg import MsgProto
from steam.enums.emsg import EMsg

message = MsgProto(EMsg.ClientAddFriend)
message.body.steamid_to_add = 76561197960265728

# client is a SteamClient() object
resp = client.send_message_and_wait(message, EMsg.ClientAddFriendResponse)
```

But how to run a game and connect to the server?

Comment: [ask] what did you try? So is not code writing service.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know what I should even TRY to write. There is not so many docs about it. If you give me a link to docs which contains info about it - you will really help me. I have an example code, so I can add it to edit.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/steam.client.builtins.html#steam.client.builtins.gameservers.SteamGameServers) mention that this method

```py
steam.client.builtins.gameservers.SteamGameServers(steam).query(filter_text, 
    max_servers=10, 
    timeout=30, 
    **kw)
```

returns a list of servers that looks like

```
[{'auth_players': 0, 'server_ip': '1.2.3.4', 'server_port': 27015},
 {'auth_players': 6, 'server_ip': '1.2.3.4', 'server_port': 27016},
 ...
]
```

Comment: I know about it. It uses Master Server Query protocol. I can get players list using Server Query protocol (A2S), but it doesn't return player's steam64 id